# how to register python modules in configuration.nix file

Tags: python, nix, nixos

i am in need of a system-wide python module 'akshare', which is not available in Nixpkgs  and can only be fetched from [Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/akshare/#copy-hash-modal-38d722af-a6b7-4bcb-9799-30a8b2b489f9), so i have tried to declare it in `my-python-packages` and then include it in `environment.systemPackages` in the configuration.nix file like below:

```bash
let
  my-python-packages = ps: with ps; [
    # ...
    (
      buildPythonPackage rec {
        pname = "akshare";
        version = "1.10.57";
        src = fetchPypi {
          inherit pname version;
          sha256 = "72b339e19d507c32193ad490ef19cf6692d82eecb7445e3567d4b2ed5ffa90e1";
        };
        doCheck = true;
        propagatedBuildInputs = [
          # Specify dependencies
          pkgs.python311Full.withPackages(ps: with ps; [ numpy ])
        ];
      }
    )
  ];
in
{
  // other configs ...
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    # Other system packages
    podman-desktop
    (python311Full.withPackages(ps: with ps; [ pandas requests polars numpy]++ my-python-packages))
    rargs
    redis
    ripgrep
  ];
  # Other configuration options
  # ...
}
```

but this somehow ends up returning upon a rebuild

```bash
error: value is a function while a list was expected

       at /nix/store/61k92av6g5yb3hg29ijjiahj06hp0h56-source/configuration.nix:360:44:

          359|   podman-desktop
          360|   (python311Full.withPackages(ps: with ps; [ pandas requests polars numpy]++ my-python-packages))
             |                                            ^
          361|   rargs
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

what is the correct method to fix this and install the module ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, `my-python-packages` is a function, not a list. You must call it and append the resultant list.

```hs
python311Full.withPackages (ps: with ps; [ pandas requests polars numpy ] ++ (my-python-packages ps))
```